# mongo db transaction with multiple collection not working

Tags: mongodb, transactions

the following function is supposed to do:

1. save the project into collection 'project_list'
2. push the uuid of the new project to a client in the collection 'client_list'
3. with transaction enabled, if anything goes wrong (such as the client id is given in the new project JSON object does not exist in the collection 'client_list'), then both step1 and step2 will be canceled.

noticed that the code is giving the client_id as 'invalid-uuid' to updateOne which will not add the project uuid to the client because the client_id does not exist in the collection but the new project is saved into collection 'project_list' with or without me doing commitTransaction.

I was reading this https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html which suggest me to abort the transaction by calling await session.abortTransaction(); but i dont know how to implement it.

thanks in advance.

```
transactionCreateProject: async function (newProjectJson) {
        const mongoConnectConfig = {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true};
        await mongoose.connect(CONSTANTS.ADMIN_MONGO_URL, mongoConnectConfig)
        const db = mongoose.connection;
        db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error：'))
        db.once("open", function (callback) {
            console.log("Connection Succeeded")
        });
    
    let project = mongoose.model('project', mongooseProjectSchema)
    let client = mongoose.model('client', mongooseClientSchema)

    const session = await mongoose.startSession();
    session.startTransaction();
    try {
        console.log(newProjectJson.clientUUID)
        let newProjectMongooseObject = new project()
        for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(newProjectJson).length; i++){
            // assigning the attributes of new project to mongoose object
            newProjectMongooseObject[Object.keys(newProjectJson)[i]] = newProjectJson[Object.keys(newProjectJson)[i]]
        }
        newProjectMongooseObject['createdAt'] = dateObject.toISOString();
        let saveRes = await newProjectMongooseObject.save()
        let addProjectToClientRes = await clientMongooseModel.updateOne({ 'uuid': "invalid-uuid"}, {$push: {'projects': { projectID: newProjectJson.uuid}}})
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        return null
    }

    finally {
        console.log("in finally, session ending")
        session.endSession();
    }

    return null
},
```

Comment: First, your usage is wrong. See https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/10008. Second, you need to pass the session to each read and write operation which you are not doing.

Comment: I went through a lot of post and still can't get it to work, the link is my latest trail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66681733/mongoose-transaction-session-withtransaction-is-not-a-function Thank you for providing me with a better approach to my problem.